# WMIC - how to use Lenovo SetBiosSetting method

Tags: wmic

I have a prob calling SetBiosSetting method using WMIC (and also C#)

wmic /namespace:\root\wmi path Lenovo_SetBiosSetting call SetBiosSetting "SecurityChip,Active"

wmic /namespace:\root\wmi path Lenovo_SetBiosSetting call SetBiosSetting SecurityChip,Active

wmic /namespace:\root\wmi path Lenovo_SetBiosSetting call SetBiosSetting ("SecurityChip,Active")

that gives "Invalid Number of Parameters." error, but why ?

Lenovo BIOS Deployment Guide: http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/hrdeploy_en.pdf

Any Idea ?
I cant use VBS or PowerShell ...

Thanks,Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in C#:

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\wmi");


        //
        // Make change(s)
        //
        SelectQuery queryRead = new SelectQuery("SELECT * from Lenovo_SetBiosSetting");
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, queryRead))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject queryItem in queryCollection)
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject inParams = queryItem.GetMethodParameters("SetBiosSetting");
                    inParams["parameter"] = "WakeOnLAN,Disable";

                    ManagementBaseObject outParams = queryItem.InvokeMethod("SetBiosSetting", inParams, null);
                    string result = outParams["return"] as string; // "Success"
                }
            }
        }


        //
        // Commit to BIOS
        //
        queryRead = new SelectQuery("SELECT * from Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings");
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, queryRead))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject queryItem in queryCollection)
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject inParams = queryItem.GetMethodParameters("SaveBiosSettings");
                    inParams["parameter"] = "";

                    ManagementBaseObject outParams = queryItem.InvokeMethod("SaveBiosSettings", inParams, null);
                    string result = outParams["return"] as string; // "Success"
                }
            }
        }
```

The PowerShell for this is:

```
(gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting("WakeOnLAN,Disable")
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this post trying to find a way to use WMIC to get all the objects in the `Lenovo_BiosSetting` class. Your syntax got me on the right track. I had to change your WMIC query to this:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path Lenovo_BiosSetting get
```

(Note the double back slash)